# Pyaudio & Threading leads to RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, pyaudio

i've got a problem with recording Audio over Pyaudio on a Raspberry Pi.
The purpose of my code is to record small audio snippets, 10s long, every 10s to 20s.

To do this, I'm starting an own Thread for the recorder:

```
# Create collect beat thread.
recorder_thread = Thread(target=beat_analyzer, args=(recorder_queue,))
recorder_thread.start()
```

It uses another class to control the timing (recorder_queue). The recording itself happens in beat_analyzer.
Somehow this is working fine for some time... but after about one hour or two, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/beatmap/bm-client/lib_recorder.py", line 134, in beat_analyzer
    py_audio.terminate()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyaudio.py", line 644, in terminate
    for stream in self._streams:
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

As I'm not iterating over something (at least I don't know about it) I wonder where the problem comes from. If it's perhaps something inside Pyaudio that I need to workaround?
Hints much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide beat_analyzer and recorder_queue source and creation? Pastebin or Gist will do - I'd like to see what really happens, because your post is not informative yet.

Comment: Sure! Would be great if you can find something: http://pastebin.com/wecS8hcY

Comment: 1. Do you run only one thread with beat_analyzer or do you run many of them? 2. Change "except:" to "except BaseException as be:" and print that exception - something happens in "try" body that causes this specific situation, lets see what is it.

Comment: There are two complete separate threads. One is doing something with the LEDs and the other one is for the beat_analyzer. The threads are not stopped or anything. Both are started separated.  I inserted the BaseException and it gives me following message:  ('Input overflowed', -9981)

Comment: I found this here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=97821 - so i altered my chunk size to CHUNK_COUNT = 8192. But that didn't solve the problem. Instead the error now occurs directly. So it seems to have something to do with the chunk size.

Comment: It's more like a bug of pyaudio not your code.

Comment: Hmm... that's not good ;) Any ideas for a workaround? Perhaps suggestions for another lib?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimenting with different chunk_count settings and also after reading laike9m's post I decided to use another library. In this case Alsaaudio - since then it works like a charme.